# Account LockOut TimeSpan overflowed

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, timespan

What I try to achieve in a .NET Core Web API is to prevent the default account lockout behavior. By default a locked out account will be unlocked after 5 minutes. In my system a locked account can only be **unlocked** by an Administrator.

In `startup.cs` the `Identity` service is configured as:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
    {
        config.Lockout = new LockoutOptions()
        {
            MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3,
            DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(Int32.MaxValue, 0, 0, 0)
        };
    });
```

So there is a property to set the `DefaultLockoutTimeSpan` and I tried making the TimeSpan as big as possible (it accepts an Int32) but it throws a `TimeSpan overflowed because the duration is too long.` exception.

I tried `DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(-1)` as well with no success.

Does anybody have a waterproof way of preventing auto unlocking of a locked-out account (after some time)? Or, less preferred, a way to make the TimeSpan as big as Possible?

Comment: Did you try `TimeSpan.MaxValue`? Ive also added an answer to remove this feature entirely

Comment: I just came across it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [IUserLockoutStore.GetLockoutEndDateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserlockoutstore-1.getlockoutenddateasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and optionally [IUserLockoutStore.SetLockoutEndDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserlockoutstore-1.setlockoutenddateasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on a custom store

All the lockout check does is see if the lockout is enabled and if so, checks if the end date has passed. If you instead return `DateTimeOffset.MaxValue` from `GetLockoutEndDateAsync` then they will always be locked out if the flag is set and regardless of whatever is set in `LockoutOptions` or in the database

Then you can override the Set method as a no-op and never store the end date at all.

Comment: What needs to happen in the override of the Set method? Set lockout enabled to true and otherwise false?

Comment: Nothing needs to happen. Just return `Task.CompletedTask`. The `SetLockoutEnabledAsync` method of the same interface will solely control the lockout

Comment: which flag are you referring to?

Comment: @symbiont https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.lockoutenabled?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

1.You could set `LockoutEnabled` to true and set the lockout end date like below:

```
await _userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, DateTime.MaxValue);
```

2.Also you could add IsEnabled field to AspNetUsers (default value is True) and override SignInManager to check value whether it is True before returning a Success result.

It is known discussion on github you could refer to [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1858).

Comment: How does this blend with the default system of locking out a user after x unsuccessful login attempts? I'd rather not add a field to the AspNetUsers table preferably.

Comment: It would implement in the default identity.If you want to know how doed it blend with.You could refer to the source code: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in IdentityConfig.cs by setting below.

```
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```